# How to install imlib2 library for Lua?

Tags: image, lua, pixel, imlib2

I have downloaded the file of lua-imlib2-0.1 from here: http://luaforge.net/projects/lua-imlib2/

How would I be able to install the library to use while i code in the terminal?

Comment: Extract the tar file, there should ideally be a ReadMe on how to install.

Comment: The ReadME just tells me that i need imlib2 installed to install lua-imlib2, and the API is fully documented.